# Translation of "и"

Tags: грамматика

I have been struggling to understand how to use “и” I know it means “and” but often I see the word and “and” doesn’t really make sense to me. Does it have alternative meanings?

For example:
“  Но я очень люблю мучные изделия, поэтому и расту как на дрожжах.”

“Да Я тебя и такую люблю”

I’ve also seen но и

Can someone help me understand.

Comment: "И" has many meanings. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8

Comment: In most cases it is intensifying "even" like in your examples.

Comment: Но и is in most cases "but also",though it depends on the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does «и» mean in the sentence like «Я и ртом надую»?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/what-does-%d0%b8-mean-in-the-sentence-like-%d0%af-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e)

Answer (score 6):

Most often “и” translates to “and”, but it's used in other ways as well. For example, it can be used before each item in an enumeration. Compare:

1. “Я купил чай, хлеб, сыр и чеснок”
2. “Я купил **и** чай, **и** хлеб, **и** сыр, **и** чеснок”

The first sentence sounds dry, a mere statement of fact: “I bought tea, bread, cheese, and garlic”. In the second sentence, by prefixing each item with “и”, the speaker highlights the **exhaustiveness** or **extensiveness** of the enumeration, as in “I bought *so many things*” or “I bought *all the things we needed*”.

When paired with other words, “и” can add emotional depth and subtext. Let's take a look at your examples:

1. “Но я очень люблю мучные изделия, поэтому **и** расту как на дрожжах.” Here “и” strengthens “поэтому”, highlighting that the consequent is obvious. You could translate it as “naturally”: “But I love baked goods, so *naturally* I grow by leaps and bounds”. It could be omitted without loss of meaning, only the tone of the text is affected.
2. “Я тебя **и** такую люблю”. Here the use of “и” means that the stated information is a surprising instance of a more general rule, much like “даже”. The sentence translates to “I love you *even* when you are like this”. A few similar examples:

   - “Мне **и** без соли вкусно” (I like the taste *even* without salt).
   - “Они **и** кошек дрессируют” (They train *even* cats)
3. “но и” translates to “but also”, and I would typically expect it to be used with “не только” (“not only”). For example, one could say “Она не только умна, **но и** трудолюбива” (She is not only smart *but also* industrious).

Answer (score 2):

Generally **и** means **and**.

Here is some Russian logic that stands behind **и** in your examples:

1. I love [bakery products] **and** [that's why I] grow. I.e. I love **and** grow.
2. Я тебя **и** такую люблю (I love you *even* when you are like that). The idea is following: I love you when you are good **and** when you are like that.

Other examples in *int-index*'s answer can be translated in a similar way: They train (other animals) **and** cats.

3. «Но и» is directly translated as *but also*, and you can see that **also** and **and** mean more or less the same.

Я люблю не только кофе, **но и** чай (Not only I like coffee **but also** tea). It means I like both coffee **and** tea.